# Google App Engine fails to deploy with message "Version not ready"

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I use Eclipse to deploy my java code to Google App Engine. But over the past two weeks I found that it very often hangs at "Verifying availability" of the frontend. After waiting for a long time with a bunch of "Will check again in 60 seconds", the deploy fails. Through trial and error, I also found out if I delete the backend or sometimes delete the version completely and do a deploy again, it is more likely to succeed. Below is the error message:

```
Unable to update:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Version not ready.
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.commit(AppVersionUpload.java:572)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:143)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:328)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:52)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:433)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:148)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use GAE Python. When I have problems with deploying an application I have to rollback first in order to deploy the application again. Sometimes deploying fails (in the way you describe) during maintance hours by the app engine team. To solve this, I had to wait a couple of hours.